# Python given location, return value at that location in 2d list?

Tags: python, loops, indexing, location

I am building a function that is given a a 2d list and a location (which is a tuple), and returns the value at that location. I'm probably confusing myself because I know how to return the index, but the problem is I don't understand how to get the function to apply the location.

Example Input/Output:

> get_value_at_location([[1]],   (0,0)) → 1
>
> get_value_at_location([[1,2],[None,1]],    (1,0)) → None

My code isn't really set because I don't understand how to apply the location. Here is what I do have:

```
def get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc):
    x= loc[0]
    y= loc[1]
    for items in range(len(puzzle)):
        for val in items:
          #go to location (x,y) and extract val
    return val
```

Comment: can you provide the value of puzzle and loc?

Comment: ex: puzzle[[1,2],[none,1],[1,2,3]] loc(0,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data being stored in puzzle (2d list), so you have to first get the row from which you need to search the value which in this case is loc[0], and then the column which is loc[1].

```
puzzle = [[1,2],[None,1]]
1st row: puzzle[0] = [1,2], puzzle[0][0] = 1, puzzle[0][1] = 2
2nd row: puzzle[1] = [None, 1], puzzle[1][0] = None, puzzle[1][1] = 1
```

try this:

```
def get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc):
    return str(puzzle[loc[0]][loc[1]])
```

Comment: @ocean.1234 the solution do return none if that is listed which is being taken care by str() which works on None, the Python null value and returns the string 'None'